# Angular not able to load another routes

Tags: angular, routes, seo, angular11

Trying to create a web application using Angular 11, I found a problem for routing:
When I navigate from initial route (

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent }
```

) to another routes everything is working as expected, but when I try to navigate the website from another route, the router redirects me to initial route.
I am not able to send a link from my web application (other than '') to another person, because the router redirects to '' (home) route.

Example:

```
const routes : Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'product/:id', component: ProductComponent }
];
```

From https://localhost:4200, when I access https://localhost:4200/product/14 works fine,
but when I try to access directly https://localhost:4200/product/14 I will be redirected to https://localhost:4200

How can i configure my angular application to be able to accept any initial route?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this:

```
const routes : Routes = [
  { path: '', 
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: 'product/:id', component: ProductComponent }
];
```

Comment: I tried this before. Still not expected behavior :(

Comment: Then we should need more info about the configuration of all the routes, the routing modules, if the code has children routes, etc.

Comment: No, only generic routes

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to -

```
const routes : Routes = [
  { path: 'home', 
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  { path: 'product/:id', component: ProductComponent },
  { path: '', 
    redirectTo: '/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
];
```

Comment: In this case I am redirected to '/home' instead of '/'.